# Direction of arrival and distance to source

Tags: mathematical-physics, signal-processing

Suppose we have $3$ receivers $a,b,c$ and one wave source which are all located on the same $XY$ plane and we do not know the position of only $c$ on the plane.

Assume a plane wave is transmitted $s(t)$ from an aribitrary point source in far field.

- Using the received signal $s_a(t)$ and $s_b(t)$ by pattern matching would it be possible to infer the direction of arrival at $a$ and $b$ and time delay of signal to reach $a$ and $b$?
- Suppose the received signal at $c$ is $s_c(t)$ would it be possible to guess the distance and direction of source to $c$ and also $(x,y)$ coordinates of $c$ with $s_a(t),s_b(t)$ and $s_c(t)$? If not what other minimal information do we need to find these?
- Is there a reference for these kind of problems for multiple sources and $XYZ$ coordinates?